# Turn off parallelization for xUnit tests in dotnet

Tags: .net-core, xunit

I'm using xUnit for tests.

When I run `dotnet test` in the console, the tests fail because of a deadlock on a database resource.

I want to see if turning off parallelization for the entire test run (that is for all selected test projects) fixes the issue.

Can I turn off paralyzation for all tests?

**Clarification**:

The project I am working on has hundreds of classes. Instead of modifying all classes (adding the same collection attribute to all test classes),  I was wondering if I can turn off parallelization for all tests in one spot. Like solution-wide setting. Or test runner setting?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can turn off parallelisation.

By default, the tests in each class are run one after the other, not in parallel, but different test classes could run in parallel.

To prevent this, define a test collection. Decorate all the classes whose tests should not run in parallel with the `Collection` attribute along with a collection  name that should be the same for all tests that should not run in parallel:

```
    [Collection("Don't run in parallel")]
    public class MyTestClass1 
    {
        //...
    }

    [Collection("Don't run in parallel")]
    public class MyTestClass2 
    {
        //...
    }
```

For more information, see https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel

There, you can see how to change the default behavior in a central location per test assembly:

> Changing Default Behavior
> There are several default pieces of behavior that can be configured by the developer as relates to running tests in parallel. These are all changed by applying an assembly level attribute:

> Put all test classes into a single test collection by default:
> [assembly: CollectionBehavior(CollectionBehavior.CollectionPerAssembly)]
> Default: CollectionBehavior.CollectionPerClass

> Set the maximum number of threads to use when running test in parallel:
> [assembly: CollectionBehavior(MaxParallelThreads = n)]
> Default: number of virtual CPUs in the PC

> Turn off parallelism inside the assembly:
> [assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]
> Default: false

> Turn off parallelism for specific Test Collection
> [CollectionDefinition(DisableParallelization = true)]
> Default: false

> Parallel-capable test collections will be run first (in parallel), followed by parallel-disabled test collections (run sequentially).

> You can only have one of these attributes per assembly; if you want to combine multiple behaviors, do it with a single attribute. Also be aware that these values affect only this assembly; if multiple assemblies are running in parallel against one another, they have their own independent values

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I understand it, xUnit won't run tests that are in the same collection. However, the project I am working on has hundreds of classes. Instead of modifying all classes,  I was wondering if I can turn off parallelization for all tests in one spot. Like solution-wide setting. Or test runner setting?

Comment: @dev.e.loper, I've addressed these concerns in an edit.